# ERROR: android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, permissions

I am getting this error as i review my application. I am unable to review and rollout the application. Please help!!

Error::
Your app has an apk with version code 1 that requests the following permission(s): android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.

Comment: Do you have a privacy policy?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/privacy-policy-guide

Comment: this is sorted. thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need any kinds of user permission you must have to add privacy police on your application and also developer console.

> Edited: Now google strickly follow privacy policy URL. If you want to
>   upload any kinds of application you have to add privacy police. Go to
>   your Store Listing and add Privacy Police Url on here.

Privacy police just nothing you have to describe your application and also mentioned about the permission.
You can easily create a privacy policy using this website: [Police](https://privacypolicies.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot brother! this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set  privacy policy in Google console. https://play.google.com/apps/publish/

Select app -> Store Presence --> Store listing -- > Privacy Policy

**Updated** ::
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?visit_id=636752736267478388-184129838&rd=1#privacy

You can refer this for more detail.

Comment: There is an option for not submitting a privacy policy this time. Cant i select that.

Comment: But it is not applicable if app is having any run time permission. i.e. android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Comment: Thanks a lot brother! This was helpful. I used link shared by  @md. tarikul islam to sort this.